# Webpack generate async loadable, splitted and cachable common code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webpack, ecmascript-6, commonschunkplugin

I'm building a **multi-page** application and am using webpack to bundle my client javascript.

I've got the following :

#### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    page1: [
      '@babel/polyfill',
      'whatwg-fetch',
      './src/scripts/page1.js'
    ],
    page2: [
      '@babel/polyfill',
      'whatwg-fetch',
      './src/scripts/page2.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: './dist/scripts/[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'scripts'),
        use: {loader: 'babel-loader'}
      }
    ]
  }
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      filename: 'common'
    })
  ]
}
```

#### page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- some code -->

    <script src="/dist/common.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/page1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### page1.js

```
import Typed from 'typed'//<- node_modules import
import myLib from './mylib.js'//<- local lib import

// some code
```

And *page2.html* and *page2.js* as so...

This is working perfectly fine

---

I would like to optimize the whole loading time, and opt for an **async** loading strategy of my scripts, but also keep my common code **splitted** to take as much as possible advantage of browser caching..

I would, idealy, like to configure `CommonsChunkPlugin` to be able to do this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- old plain synchronous load -->
    <script src="/dist/minimalWebpackSorcellery.js"></script>

    <!-- async load -->
    <script async src="/dist/page1.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- some code -->
  </body>
</html>
```

...having the plugin do the following :

- extract webpack code into one small file that I can require synchronously (that I'd add into a `<script>`)
- extract common code, bundled from webpack like `@babel/polyfill` but also `require`d modules like `typed` from node_module or `./myLib.js` from local (that I'd add into an async `<script async>`)
- extract entry specific code (that asynchrously via `webPackJsonp` require the previous)

---

> Is that possible in a simple motion ?
>
> Am I correct that's the way I should do this ?

I've been playing with `async`, `children` and stuff, but I can't get it working

Comment: Have you taken a look at this great post by Sean Larkin? https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-bits-getting-the-most-out-of-the-commonschunkplugin-ab389e5f318